# How to send variables to a custom theme from a custom module

Tags: theming, hooks

I'm trying to pass a variable from a custom module to a custom theme. I have a Controller class in a custom module

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\course_catalog\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

Class CourseCatalog extends ControllerBase {
  public function build() {

    $item = 'Test content';

    return [
      '#theme' => 'region__content',
      '#item' => $item,
    ];
  }
}
```

And this `hook_theme()` in the `.module`

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function course_catalog_theme() {
  return [
    'region__content' => [
      'variables' => ['item' => NULL]
    ]
  ];
}
```

Lastly I have my custom theme I have `region--content.html.twig`

```
<h2>Content: {{ item }}</h2>
```

This `item` value never render on the page. Have I missed something here ?

Comment: region--content is not a custom template. Use a different name not derived from a core template.

Comment: @4uk4 I have tried with other names. I have a template named `course-list.html.twig`. Didn't work with that either.

Comment: Is the twig file located in the `templates` folder? Have you tried using `{{ dump(item) }}` to see what is inside the variable? And have you cleared Drupal cache?

Answer (score 0):

Below Should work. In your hook_theme inside .module, set the variable you want as array or value in the variables.

```
$item = 'Test content';
'variables' => [
      'content' => 'content value from .module hook_theme ',
      'item' => $item,
       
    ],
```

Check the spelling of template file inside .module file or controller and that it actually exists in /templates.